# Работа с valarray и струкутрами

Tags: c++, структуры, stl

Есть некоторая структура.

```
struct Chain{
  int x;
  int y;

  Chain operator+=(int k){
      x+=k;
      y+=2;
      return *this;
  }
};
```

Есть valarray типа Chain

```
zero = {0,0};
valarray <Chain> bead(zero,size);
```

Хочется использовать типо такого

```
bead+=5;
```

И добиться поведения, которое представлено в структуре. т.е из каждого элемента из bead его `x` изменялось на `k`, а `у` ровно на два

Comment: Как добиться этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Chain {
    int x;
    int y;
    Chain(int k = 0) : x(k), y(0) {}
    Chain& operator+=(const Chain& k) {
        x += k.x;
        y += k.y + 2;
        return *this;
    }   
};

int main() {
    Chain zero; 
    valarray <Chain> bead(zero, 3);
    bead += 5; //5 неявно преобразится Chain(5)
    for (auto c : bead)
        cout << c.x << ' ' << c.y << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `+=` должен быть определен для типа, который содержит контейнер (`Chain` в вашем случае), поэтому просто передать число не получится.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

struct S
{
    int x, y;

    S operator += (const S &k)
    {
        x += k.x;
        y += k.y;
        return *this;
    }
};

void print(const std::valarray <S> &arr)
{
    for (const auto &s: arr) {
        std::cout << s.x << " " << s.y << "|";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

main()
{
    std::valarray <S> arr({0, 0}, 3);
    print(arr);  // 0 0|0 0|0 0|

    arr += {3, 2};
    print(arr);  // 3 2|3 2|3 2|
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы могли бы объявить оператор `+=` для типов `std::valarray<Chain>` и `int`.

Это даст вам возможность делать `bead+=5;`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

struct Chain{
  int x;
  int y;

  Chain operator+=(int k){
      x+=k;
      y+=2;
      return *this;
  }
};

void print_bead(const std::valarray <Chain> & input)
{
    for (const Chain & c: input)
    {
        std::cout << c.x << " " << c.y << "   ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void operator+=(std::valarray<Chain> & arr, const int amount)
{
    std::for_each(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [amount](Chain & c)
    {
        c+= amount;
    });
}


int main()
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = 3;

    std::valarray <Chain> bead({0, 0}, size);

    print_bead(bead); // 0 0   0 0   0 0

    bead += 5;

    print_bead(bead); // 5 2   5 2   5 2

    bead += 1;

    print_bead(bead); // 6 4   6 4   6 4   
}
```